# how to save html form data into .csv file using jsp

Tags: forms, jsp, csv

i am developing a website just using jsp and html. In my project I have a form where each user will input some information about them  and when the users submits the form the values should be saved into a .csv file.

Please help me in this regard.

thanks in advance

enamul

Comment: Help me doing what? We won't do everything for you. Show us what you tried, tell us where you have a specific problem, and we'll happily help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After submit form post data at specified uri defined in form action attribute:

```
<form action="http://your_damain/your_uri">
```

You need servlet or better spring controller that will processing post request fro /your_uri. Should be defined in web.xml. In this servlet you can get your properties and write tham to csv file:

```
// Get property by name
String someProperty = request.getProperty("property_name")

// Get all properties to iterate and write into file
Map properties = request.getProperties();
```

Writing in file can be done with FileOutputStream. This is easy, think you can handle it.